# SCHTASKS won't execute at scheduled time automatically

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-task-scheduler

I have a schtask task called asset which won't execute automatically at the scheduled time 5:00am. I would however point out it ran automatically at it's scheduled time perfectly until recently. The asset task simply runs a php script.

```
schtasks /create /tn "ASSET" /tr "C:\xampp\php\php.exe c:\xampp\htdocs\asset\assetemailscheduler.php" /sc daily /st 05:00:00
```

When I explicitly run asset the task it works perfectly.

```
schtask /run /tn asset
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Control Panel, Click Administrative Tools. Click the Task Scheduler. Now we must assign a user to the asset task at hand and a password. This resolved the shut down issues for me. The user I assigned to the asset task was my self. I assigned my own account to the asset task and provided my password. It's worth noting when you change your password. You must also update the password in the Task Scheduler for the asset task.